# Make only enumeration of restriction default value in jaxb

Tags: java, xml, xsd, jaxb

I have something like this in xsd (which I cannot edit):

```
<xsd:simpleType name="Foo">
    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
        <xsd:enumeration value="BAR"/>
    </xsd:restriction>
</xsd:simpleType>
```

JAXB generates this java code in class representing element, which has `Foo` as child:

```
    public Foo getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(Foo value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
```

But there is only one possible value of `Foo`, so I would prefer to see something like this in my java code:

```
public Foo getValue() {
    if( value == null )
    {
        return Foo.BAR; //Foo already is defined as enum, so this code is fine
    }
    return value;
}
```

Is there some easy way to make this happen in JAXB?

Answer (score 1):

to sum up, you are expecting a default value for Foo ? if so try to add a default value on the  Foo type element instead.

see http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-0/#OccurrenceConstraints for default value

Comment: Yes, I am expecting a default value for Foo. But as I have already said, I cannot edit schema (it is supplied by the governmental organization).

Comment: So you can't get what you want in an easy way (except modifying manually the code as you made, but you will have to modify it each time your files are re-generated which is ugly). Is there a reason that you need such a "weird" code ? Keep and use the enum Foo as it.